# How to search certain subdirectories of directories that are ignored by Git

Tags: spacemacs, helm, search, git

I'm working in a Scala project that has `target/` directories entered as ignored in the `.gitignore`. However, there is also Scala code being generated during the build which is being nested under a `target/` directory, which I want to have included in my search. If I remove the `target/` entry from `.gitignore`, the search picks it up (and lots of other junk). However, I don't really want to exclude these files from being ignored by Git, because they are not supposed to be committed. I just want to exclude them from being ignored by searching.

I am using the `develop` (prerelease 0.300) version of Spacemacs, with Helm. An example of a search command I am using is `SPC s P` (*search project w/input*) which I press while the cursor is on some identifier that I want to find in project files. I have both `ag` and `grep` installed. I don't know what Helm is using to search (maybe even `git grep`?).

`SPC SPC describe-key RET SPC s P`:

```
SPC s P runs the command spacemacs/helm-project-smart-do-search-region-or-symbol
(found in evil-normal-state-local-map), which is an interactive Lisp function in
‘../../funcs.el’.

It is bound to SPC *, SPC s P, M-m *, M-m s P.

(spacemacs/helm-project-smart-do-search-region-or-symbol)

Search in current project using ‘dotspacemacs-search-tools’ with
 default input.
 Search for a search tool in the order provided by ‘dotspacemacs-search-tools’.
```

What's the best way to essentially add a rule `!foo/target/**/*.scala` for the sake of search, but not of Git?

Comment: Can you specify the command used when you press `SPC s P`?

Comment: @jagrg Not sure, haven't got good at finding that kind of thing yet.

Comment: Try `M-x describe-key RET SPC s P`.

Comment: @jagrg thank you. Updated the question with that info.

Answer (score 2):

### Choose your tool

If you have installed `ag` and not `rg` then `ag` will be used according to the documentation string in your dotfile you can see that Spacemacs tries the search tool in this order first `rg`, then `ag`, `pt`, `ack` and finally `grep`.

### Hack your tool

One solution is to use the options of the tool you are using in your case for `ag`:

- create a `.agignore` ignore file at the root of your project
- invoke `helm-project-smart-do-search`
- when helm prompt you for the pattern to search, prefix your search pattern with `-U` as follow `pattern: -U <pattern to search>`
  Note that `-U` is an option of `ag` that allows you to ignore the VCS ignore files but still uses the `.agignore`.

Side note: for `rg` you can set a directory local variable RIPGREP_CONFIG_PATH with the right path to a `.ripgreprc` where you store the default options for the ripgrep searches in this project.

### Maybe there a better way

With some efforts there should be a way to design a Spacemacs solution to organize ignore lists independently of the search tool or the VCS used. I don't know if it's very useful though most of the people like me tends to stick to same one search tool and VCS.